# SQLAlchemy: create an intentionally empty query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What's the best way to create an intentionally empty query in SQLAlchemy?

For example, I've got a few functions which build up the query (adding `WHERE` clauses, for example), and at some points I know that the the result will be empty.

What's the best way to create a query that won't return any rows? Something like Django's `QuerySet.none()`.

Comment: What is the reason you would like to replace the no-row-returning query with the fake one? Do you still need the return-type (a mapped object or so) to be preserved?

Comment: Two reasons: the first would be performance (and to avoid the warning which is issued when testing membership against an empty list (ex, `foo.in_([])`)), and the second would be readability (ex, `if user.has_no_permissions(): return empty()`)

Comment: Why don't you just return an empty `list/tuple` [second question in my first comment]?

Comment: .. and if you need the proper return type, just return `session.query(MyObject).filter("0==1")`. When evaluated, this will still hit the DB, but it should be fast.

Comment: I don't return a a list or tuple because I'd like to return a query (well, specifically, an `Expression`) so that future code can modify it (ex, `get_permitted_blog_posts(user).where(BlogPost.c.post_date > first_post)`). And I could add a `WHERE 1 = 2` type clause, but I'm wondering if there's any "blessed" method, similar to Django's `EmptyQuerySet()`.

Comment: Another way to describe the problem is the need to have "Null Object" pattern for queries. It needs to behave like a normal query in every respect, but on evaluation it would efficiently produce the empty set. I ended up solving that problem using the None object, not ideal, but that appears to be the way SQLAlchemy is meant to be used.

Answer (score 36):

If you need the proper return type, just return `session.query(MyObject).filter(sqlalchemy.sql.false())`.

When evaluated, this will still hit the DB, but it should be fast.

If you don't have an ORM class to "query", you can use `false()` for that as well:
`session.query(sqlalchemy.false()).filter(sqlalchemy.false())`

Answer (score 7):

```
db_session(YourModel).query.filter(False)
```

Comment: Not an answer to my problem, but helped be to solve my issue. I need to apply some filter if it is provided, or to get all items if no filter is provided. I just used True to get all items in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg25783.html, as of Dec. 11, 2011, there is no `EmptyQuery` type object in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Use python's `True` boolean literal:

```
_and(True, some_other_query, True, True)
```

is the same as:

```
some_other_query
```